# How to understand "nonlinear" as in "nonlinear dimensionality reduction"?

Tags: pca, terminology, dimensionality-reduction, pattern-recognition, manifold-learning

I am trying to understand the differences between the linear dimensionality reduction methods (e.g., PCA) and the nonlinear ones (e.g., Isomap).

I cannot quite understand what the (non)linearity implies in this context. I read from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) that

> By comparison, if PCA (a linear dimensionality reduction algorithm) is
>   used to reduce this same dataset into two dimensions, the resulting
>   values are not so well organized. This demonstrates that the
>   high-dimensional vectors (each representing a letter 'A') that sample
>   this manifold vary in a non-linear manner.

What does

> the high-dimensional vectors (each representing a letter 'A') that
>   sample this manifold vary in a non-linear manner.

mean? Or more broadly, how do I understand the (non)linearity in this context?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Dimensionality reduction means that you map each many-dimensional vector into a low-dimensional vector. In other words, you represent (replace) each many-dimensional vector by a low-dimensional vector.

Linear dimensionality reduction means that components of the low-dimensional vector are given by linear functions of the components of the corresponding high-dimensional vector. For example in case of reduction to two dimensions we have:

```
[x1, x2, ..., xn] ->  [f1(x1, x2, ..., xn), f2(x1, x2, ..., xn)]
```

If `f1` and `f2` are (non)linear functions, we have a (non)linear dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Just to be clear, you should add that "linear" in this context means $f(a\cdot x + b) = a\cdot f(x) + b$, or some generalized equivalent. For instance, each PCA dimension is a "linear combination" of the inputs: $w_1x_1 + \dots + w_nx_n$.

Comment: What I mean is: $f_i = f_i (x_1, \dots, x_n) = c^{(i)} + \omega^{(i)}_1 x_1 + \dots \omega^{(i)}_n x_n$, where $f_i$ and $x_i$ are the components of the low- and high-dimensional vectors, respectively (and I think it is not what you mean). I thought that the problem was not in the understanding what a linear function is but in where the linearity appears.

Comment: Your definition explains why PCA and Factor analysis are linear dimensionality reduction methods, but it can't explain why NNMF (non-negative matrix factorization) is a linear dimensionality reduction method (NNMF usually noted as linear dimensionality reduction, see [here](https://bitsandbrains.io/2018/09/25/linear-dimensionality-reduction.html) for example). In NNMF we do the following projection $X \to W H$, so there is no $X$ matrix at the right side at all (unlike PCA, which do $X \to XW$).

Answer (score 56):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: PCA vs Isomap]

Here we are looking for 1-dimensional structure in 2D. The points lie along an S-shaped curve. PCA tries to describe the data with a *linear* 1-dimensional manifold, which is simply a line; of course a line fits these data quite bad. Isomap is looking for a *nonlinear* (i.e. curved!) 1-dimensional manifold, and should be able to discover the underlying S-shaped curve.

Comment: Does this mean that we can define methods of linear dimensionality reduction as methods which map original high-dimensional points to the set of points which lie on some linear low-dimensional manifold? And similarly define methods of nonlinear dimensionality reduction as methods which map original high-dimensional points to the set of points which lie on some non-linear low-dimensional manifold?